# Passagem de array como parâmetro de uma função

Tags: php, array, parâmetros

Quero receber o *array* contendo os números 3, 15 e 23 e com um *array* de saída exibir o dobro. Só que está dando o seguinte erro:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for criando_array(), called in

```
<?php

function criando_array($array){

            $array = array();

            return $array;
    }

    function dobrar_array(){

        $dobrar = criando_array();

        foreach($dobrar as $lista){

            echo $lista*2 . "<br>";
        }

    }

    $resposta =  dobrar_array(array(3, 15, 23));

    echo $resposta;


?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O código tem alguns problemas, ele pode ser muito mais simples:

```
<?php
function dobrar_array($dobrar) { //agora está recebendo um parâmetro aqui
    //a função que era chamada aqui não era necessária e não fazia nada útil
    foreach($dobrar as $lista){
        echo $lista*2 . "<br>";
    }
}
$resposta = dobrar_array(array(3, 15, 23));
echo $resposta;
?>
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/8ahp52). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FunctionParam). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/FunctionParam.php).

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou corretamente.

Answer (score 7):

A função `criando_array()` não tem muito sentido o que ela faz é receber um parâmentro com valores, depois essa mesma variável(`$array`) recebece um array vazio que é retornado ao final da função.

O erro está aqui na sintaxe, `criando_array` precisa de uma entra que é obrigatório como mostra sua assinatura:

```
function criando_array($array){
```

Olhe como está sendo feita a chamada:

```
 function dobrar_array(){
    $dobrar = criando_array(); // deveria ser algo como $dobrar = criando_array($variavel);
```

Sugiro que na função `dobrar_array` defina um parâmetro para para fazer a multiplicação diretamente e também pode descarte a função `criando_array`

```
function dobrar_array($array){
    foreach($array as $lista){
        echo $lista * 2 ."<br>";
    }
}

 dobrar_array(array(3, 15, 23)); 
 // ou ainda
 $array = array(3, 15, 23);
 dobrar_array($array);
```

Comment: Seu comentário me ajudou. Obrigado Cara.

Answer (score 4):

Para utilizar um array como parametro, basta na função fazer o seguinte:

```
function dobrar_array($parametro=array()){

        foreach($parametro as $lista){

            echo $lista*2 . "<br>";
        }

    }

    $resposta =  dobrar_array(array(3, 15, 23));

    echo $resposta;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Deu uma clareada aqui.